# tuple() not working fully with files in python

Tags: python, tuples

So i am trying to copy all the lines present in a file into a list. From a previous question on here I found out this method of copying all the lines into a list.The problem I am facing is that not all the contents of the file are getting copied to the list.

```
names = tuple(open("MusicNames.txt", 'r'))
names2 = tuple(open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'r'))
print names
print names2
```

this is what I am doing to copy the names but after a particular line the list stops appending and the last item in the list doesn't contain the whole line.
What could be causing such an error?

Okay i shall include my full code right now. When I commented out the part of the code where I am writing to the file it worked properly.
Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/Q7W3VXPi

Comment: "copy all the lines to a list"... so `open("MusicNames.txt", 'r').readlines()`?

Comment: I have tried that also it still stops at the exact same place. Also I have checked the file I am opening it does contain lines after the place it stops.

Comment: Do you want them in a list or a tuple? They're different primitives in python.

Comment: Can you provide file you are working with? Or at least the string that causing behavior?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some further details if you want I can upload the text files also

Comment: Are you sure the file you're checking is the file that Python is reading? Maybe you have two different versions of the file in two different directories. Try `import os; print os.getcwd()` to confirm that your current working directory is what you expect.

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe "F:/Python Projects/MusicOrganizer/MusicOrganiser.py"
F:\Python Projects\MusicOrganizer
This is what this prints and i have checked there is only 1 file with that name in the directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close your file objects after you're done writing to them. Otherwise, it is possible that all of your changes won't be flushed to the actual file by the time you read from it.

```
fp2 = open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'w')

#writing to fp2 goes here...

fp2.close()

#now you are ready to open the file again.
names2 = tuple(open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'r'))
```

If you find it burdensome to write both `open` and `close` methods, you can use the `with` statement, which will do the closing for you.

```
with open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'w') as fp2:
    #writing to fp2 goes here....

#now you are ready to open the file again.
names2 = tuple(open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'r'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this seemed to fix this problem. Is there any reason why the changes were not getting flushed to the file?

Comment: AFAIK, it's a common optimization employed by programming languages to not actually perform file I/O every time you ask it to. It's less work on the OS if it saves up batches of modifications in memory, only writing to the actual file when a substantial amount of data is accumulated. The drawback being, you can catch the language by surprise by opening the file a second time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get a full list of lines

```
 names = [line for line in open("MusicNames.txt", 'r')]
 names2 = [line for line in open("MusicNamesOtherFolder.txt", 'r')]
```

Comment: Why not `names = list(open("MusicNames.txt", 'r'))`?

Comment: The problem seems to be something completely different from this now. But thanks for your answer.